# Unable to access a property on a variable within a function. Uncaught TypeError:

Tags: javascript, html, function, object

I have a trivia app that is importing an array of objects called "questions". I have used getElementById to capture each of the buttons, and also added click event listeners for the "checkAnswer" function below.

However, I am getting the error: Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "correct", answer is undefined. This happens with any button I click.

I am using type="module" within the script tag in the HTML file.

The buttons are populating the correct text, but are not console logging any text like it should.

"randomQuestion" is a global variable that is being generated in another function within the same file. This is what it looks like:

```
  randomQuestion = questions[Math.floor(Math.random()*questions.length)];
```

```js
function checkAnswer(bntIndex) {
  answer = randomQuestion.answers[bntIndex];
  if (answer.correct === true) {
    console.log("Correct!");
  } else {
    console.log("Incorrect");
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear where you have `checkAnswer` defined. If it's in script.js, then you can't use that function in `onclick`, since it's defined in a module, and therefore not defined on the global object. If you were to use `addEventListener` to attach your event handlers to the event listeners, it would be less of a problem.

Comment: I removed the onClick event from the HTML. I added getElementById for each button, and added event listeners for each button. now  I'm getting an error with my "answer" variable: Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "correct", answer is undefined.

I tried adding indexes to the buttons, and tried appending the answer variable with "questions".

What could make this happen?

Comment: [Edit] your question with a [mre].

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure if I did what you asked right. But there above is the problem I am having.

Comment: So, I've added a Stack Snippet to your question. Currently, when I click "Run code snippet", I get errors because you forgot the ending brace `}` for the function. Even with that, it won't work because nothing calls `checkAnswer`,  and `nextButton`, `randomQuestion`, `incrementPoiints`, and `result` are all undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It's rather a warning than an error.

You are getting those because you don't export this function and also don't use it anywhere